# Wordpress Json Decode

Tags: wordpress

Here is my sample json

```
`a:3:{s:6:"prefix";s:2:"Mr";s:10:"first-name";s:3:"Ben";s:9:"last-name";s:7:"Richman";}`
```

I want to get prefix, first-name and lastname as array or orject in php. I am currently working in Wordpress. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because it is saved as serialized data vs json.

You can use PHP unserialize to convert it.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: Thanks. It is working. I have been doing json_decode().